# Cakephp HABTM relation

Tags: database, cakephp, relationship, mapping

i have theses tables 
article , article_currency, currency in database 
and i made HABTM between article and currency like this

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('currency'=>array('className' => 'currency','joinTable'=>'article_currency','foreignKey' => 'articleid','associationForeignKey' => 'CurrencyID'));

var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('articlemodel'=>array('className' => 'articlemodel','joinTable'=>'article_currency','foreignKey' => 'CurrencyID','associationForeignKey' => 'ArticleID'));
```

and here cake genrate the model **ArticleCurrency** for me 
when i try to change its name using **with**  to 'article_currency'
is give me this error
***Database table article_currencies for model article_currency was not found.***

how i can solve this

Answer (score 3):

Table names are plural by convention: articles, currencies, articles_currencies

http://book.cakephp.org/view/24/Model-and-Database-Conventions

Comment: i dont; want to stuck with cakephp convention

Comment: in that case use can use the model-attribute `useTable` to let Cake know how you named the table

http://book.cakephp.org/view/436/useTable